# QtWebEngine Causing Segmentation Fault on MacOS with PyQT. What is going wrong?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qtwebengine

I built a basic app to test QtWebEngine functionality on MacOS because my larger more complex app isn't working with WebEngine either. Both apps (the complex one, and this one), work on Windows.

Code:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
# use the QtWebEngineWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import *
# start my_app
my_app = QApplication(sys.argv)
# open webpage
my_web = QWebEngineView()
my_web.load(QUrl("http://www.google.com"))
my_web.show()
# sys exit function
sys.exit(my_app.exec())
```

Result:

[image: Screenshot of bug]

As you can see, nothing gets rendered. It's not a blank web page, it's just that the widget does not render.

MacOS Mojave 10.14.3, PyQT5 5.14.0, PyQTWebEngine 5.14.0

I installed PyQT5 and PyQTWebEngine via Pip on MacOS. What should I do?

Edit:

I have updated to try out some debugging with signals, the code is here:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
# use the QtWebEngineWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import *
# start my_app
my_app = QApplication(sys.argv)
# open webpage

def load_started():
    print("Load started")

def load_finished(x):
    print("Load finished", x)

def load_started():
    print("Load started")

def load_progress(x):
    print("Load progress: ", x)

try:
    my_web = QWebEngineView()
    my_web.load(QUrl("http://www.google.com"))
    my_web.show()
    my_web.loadStarted.connect(load_started)
    my_web.loadProgress.connect(lambda x: load_progress(x))
    my_web.loadFinished.connect(lambda x: load_finished(x))


except Exception as e:
    print(e)
# sys exit function
sys.exit(my_app.exec())
```

The result in the working Windows machine is

```
Load progress:  10
Load started
Load progress:  21
Load progress:  29
Load progress:  60
Load progress:  100
Load finished True
Load progress:  100
Load progress:  100
```

The result in the non-working MacOS is:

```
Load started
Load progress:  0
Load progress:  100
```

Note how it never emits the "load finished" signal

Edit 2: There happens to be a "renderProcessTerminated" signal. This signal is emitting terminationStatus = 2 (The render process crashed, for example because of a segmentation fault.) And exit code = 11 (seems to mean segmentation fault, but not sure)

So now the question is.. what is causing this crash and error?

Comment: You can connect to one or more of the myriad [signals](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebenginepage.html#signals) of the associated [`QWebEnginePage`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebengineview.html#page) to see whether or not the load starts/progresses.

Comment: @G.M. Thanks for the heads up. I have updated the post with the result of checking the signals. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can't reproduce I'm afraid.  Works as expected for me on MacOS 10.13.6 High Sierra with Qt5.13.2 (installed using [homebrew](https://brew.sh/)).  The render process crashing is odd though.  Perhaps there's a dependency/package version mismatch somewhere.  Just a guess though.

Comment: @Jason I have seen similar problems in the past with Qt Webengine on MacOS/Windows and the cause was the drivers, try to update your drivers.

Comment: @G.M. I think it might be an OpenGL issue of some kind but either way I shouldn't be getting it. What methods did you use to install PyQt5 and PyWebEngineView?

Comment: @Jason `PyQt5` and `Qt5` were installed using homebrew.  Not sure what you mean by `PyWebEngineView` -- or were you just referring to `QWebEngineView`?

Comment: @G.M. Ok, I'll give Homebrew a shot. Sorry, I meant PyQtWebEngine, not PyWebEngineView. Do you have that installed? https://pypi.org/project/PyQtWebEngine/

Comment: @Jason I don't have `PyQtWebEngine` installed as far as I'm aware.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing worked, tried a bunch of different install configs, new environments via venv, conda, updated MacOS to Catalina (latest version), etc.

Conclusion: 5.14 is broken. Downgraded everything to 5.12 and it worked. Took way too long but least I learned a bunch about Python environments.